# Como trazer a bolinha selecionada para frente (z-index maior) no Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

Na series, tenho o evento legendItemClick, que quando clico na legenda ele seta a bolinha como hover. Gostaria de saber como faço para trazer a mesma para frente?

```
legendItemClick: function () {                           
                        resetaState();
                        //this.zIndex = 1000;
                        //this.toFront();
                        this.redraw();
                        this.data[0].setState('hover');

                       return false;
                    }
                }
```

Testei, setando o z-index e utilizando o método toFront, mas não obtive sucesso.

Answer (score 1):

Tente utilizar o `z-index` com um valor maior, ex: `999999` e lembre-se que o z-index só funciona com `position` informado, ex: `position:relative; z-index:999999;`